# Python try block size

Tags: python, django, exception, coding-style

It is possible to maximize or minimize try-except block.

Sometimes i dont know, which style I must stick.

Example with Django:

- Long block:

  ```
  try:
      entity1 = Entity1.objects.get(id=1)
      entity2 = Entity2.objects.get(id=1)
      print somedict['unexistantkey']
      some.another.logic()
  except Entity1.DoesNotExists:
      # do something
  except Entity2.DoesNotExists:
      # do something
  except KeyError:
      # do something
  except CustomDomainException:
      # do somethong
  ```
- Short blocks:

  ```
  try:
      entity1 = Entity1.objects.get(id=1)
  except Entity1.DoesNotExists:
      # do something

  try:
      entity2 = Entity2.objects.get(id=1)
  except Entity2.DoesNotExists:
      # do something

  try:
      print somedict['unexistantkey']
  except KeyError:
      # do something

  try:
      some.another.logic()
  except CustomDomainException:
      # do somethong
  ```

Which case is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do different things, so which one you use depends on what you're trying to do.  The first one catches any error in *any* of the four lines inside the try block that matches &any* of the `except` clauses.  The second version only catches one kind of exception per line of "tried" code.  For instance, the first version will catch a KeyError if one is raised from the line `entity1 = Entity1.objects.get(id=1)`; the second version will not catch such an error, since there is no `except KeyError` clause for that line.

That said, in general it's a good idea to keep `try` blocks short.  If the only error you want to handle for the first line is `Entity1.DoesNotExist`, then use the second approach.  In this case, a KeyError will "count" as a real exception and will propagate upwards instead of being caught by this code, which is probably what you want.  Using long `try` blocks with lots of `except` clauses can result in errors being caught when you didn't actually want to catch them.  However, it can make sense to have such blocks if you really do want to catch any of the specified exceptions, no matter where in the block it occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Short blocks should be prefered.

Comment: Is there any PEP8 rule, or similar, regarding this?

Comment: Yes, there is: "[Additionally, for all try/except clauses, limit the try clause to the absolute minimum amount of code necessary.](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)"

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

For the objects in django, you could use the shortcuts `get_or_create`, `get_object_or_404` or `get_list_or_404`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404

For the dictionary you should use `print somedict.get('unexistantkey')`

It will return `None` instead of a KeyError.

If you want to do something for a non existing key you could do:

```
variable = somedict.get('unexistantkey')

if not variable:
    print 'does not exist'
```

These will allow you to structure your code in a more readable way.